Building protobuf for CPP
I'm trying to use protobuf for my application.
I would like to link it to run my programm
Steps I did

install via homebrew brew install protobuf
checked if abseil is included (hence the error I'm getting) brew list --versions abseil
updated my linker flags like  this

/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++17 -fdiagnostics-color=always -I/Users/me/dev/customDev/cpp/tiny_db/generated -g /Users/me/dev/customDev/cpp/tiny_db/include/tiny_db.pb.cc /Users/me/dev/customDev/cpp/tiny_db/main.cpp -o /Users/me/dev/customDev/cpp/tiny_db/main -lprotobuf


build my protofile protoc --cpp_out=./include tiny_db.proto
Included it in my main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <fstream>
#include "include/tiny_db.pb.h"

I'm getting following error
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "void absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::LogMessage::CopyToEncodedBuffer<(absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::LogMessage::StringType)0>(std::__1::basic_string_view<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>)", referenced from:
      absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::LogMessage& absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::LogMessage::operator<<<19>(char const (&) [19]) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
  "absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::LogMessage& absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::LogMessage::operator<<<unsigned long, 0>(unsigned long const&)", referenced from:
      absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::LogMessage::operator<<(unsigned long) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
  "absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int, std::__1::basic_string_view<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>)", referenced from:
      Value::SharedDtor() in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      Value::MergeImpl(google::protobuf::MessageLite&, google::protobuf::MessageLite const&) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      google::protobuf::MessageLite::ClassData::full() const in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      Key::SharedDtor() in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      Key::MergeImpl(google::protobuf::MessageLite&, google::protobuf::MessageLite const&) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      KeyValue::SharedDtor() in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      KeyValue::MergeImpl(google::protobuf::MessageLite&, google::protobuf::MessageLite const&) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      KeyValue::MergeImpl(google::protobuf::MessageLite&, google::protobuf::MessageLite const&) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      KeyValue::MergeImpl(google::protobuf::MessageLite&, google::protobuf::MessageLite const&) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      ...
  "absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()", referenced from:
      Value::SharedDtor() in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      Value::SharedDtor() in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      Value::MergeImpl(google::protobuf::MessageLite&, google::protobuf::MessageLite const&) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      Value::MergeImpl(google::protobuf::MessageLite&, google::protobuf::MessageLite const&) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      google::protobuf::MessageLite::ClassData::full() const in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      google::protobuf::MessageLite::ClassData::full() const in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      Key::SharedDtor() in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      Key::SharedDtor() in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      ...
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::MakeCheckOpString<void const*, void const*>(void const*, void const*, char const*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::Check_NEImpl<Value const*, Value*>(Value const* const&, Value* const&, char const*) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::Check_NEImpl<Key const*, Key*>(Key const* const&, Key* const&, char const*) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::Check_NEImpl<KeyValue const*, KeyValue*>(KeyValue const* const&, KeyValue* const&, char const*) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::Check_NEImpl<KeyValueStore const*, KeyValueStore*>(KeyValueStore const* const&, KeyValueStore* const&, char const*) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::MakeCheckOpString<long long, long long>(long long, long long, char const*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::Check_GEImpl<int, int>(int const&, int const&, char const*) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::Check_GTImpl<int, int>(int const&, int const&, char const*) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::Check_LTImpl<int, int>(int const&, int const&, char const*) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::Check_EQImpl<int, int>(int const&, int const&, char const*) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
  "absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::CheckOpMessageBuilder::ForVar2()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::MakeCheckOpString<unsigned long long, long long>(unsigned long long, long long, char const*) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
  "absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::MakeCheckOpString<unsigned long long, long long>(unsigned long long, long long, char const*) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
  "absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::CheckOpMessageBuilder::CheckOpMessageBuilder(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>* absl::lts_20240722::log_internal::MakeCheckOpString<unsigned long long, long long>(unsigned long long, long long, char const*) in tiny_db-9b57b9.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Linking abseil now (-labsl_base -labsl_log_internal -labsl_strings -labsl_log_severity) gives me
ld: library 'absl_log_internal' not found
checking installed abseil (auto installed along with protobuf abseil 20240722.0)
How can I build my cpp file?
EDIT I saw the post about How do I properly link the Google Protocol Buffers library with my application at compilation?
anyhow, I dont want to build protobuf from source but rather hoped to get it working on a more convenient way

see the path that pkg-conf gives you for absl library. add -L flag to your link stage.

checked that
/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++17 -fdiagnostics-color=always -I/usr/local/Cellar/abseil/20240722.0/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/abseil/20240722.0/lib -labsl -I/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/28.3/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/28.3/lib -lprotobuf -I/Users/me/dev/customDev/cpp/tiny_db/include -g /Users/me/dev/customDev/cpp/tiny_db/main.cpp -o /Users/me/dev/customDev/cpp/tiny_db/main

gives me
1 warning generated.
ld: library 'absl' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

got it  working that way
/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++17 -fdiagnostics-color=always $(pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf) -I/Users/me/dev/customDev/cpp/tiny_db/include -g /Users/challmann/dev/customDev/cpp/tiny_db/main.cpp /Users/challmann/dev/customDev/cpp/tiny_db/include/tiny_db.pb.cc -o /Users/challmann/dev/customDev/cpp/tiny_db/main
I'm not getting why it does not work when linking directling using L/usr/local/Cellar/abseil/20240722.0/lib  anyhow

i donno about exact library names. use pkg-conf --libs your_library_package_name to see the flags that you should pass. why did not you pass flags that you'd used in OP?

good that you got it working. try to "shell in" tiny-db. it will make linker command shorter and more readable. you can combine all libs into one command. like pkg-conf --cflags --libs protobuf tiny-db.

This question is similar to: OpenCV Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: error. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@user14063792468 at the beginning it was not obvious for me if it is a linking error or a  general issue with the lib. hence the post.
Given the results of my finding, I agree with you.
Please feel free to lock or delete the post. If you like , I can also add the solution to complement as an answer

yeah, the answer will be good.

I couldn't get a shell task json build working, but I was able to leverage the output of pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf and build it using that.
Since I'm using VSC, my task json looks like this
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": [
            "-std=c++17",
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",

            "-I/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/28.3/include",
            "-I/usr/local/Cellar/abseil/20240722.0/include",
            "-I/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/28.3/include",
            "-I/usr/local/Cellar/abseil/20240722.0/include",
            "-I${fileDirname}/include",
            "-L/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/28.3/lib",
            "-L/usr/local/Cellar/abseil/20240722.0/lib",
            "-L/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/28.3/lib",
            "-L/usr/local/Cellar/abseil/20240722.0/lib",
            "-lprotobuf",
            "-labsl_log_internal_check_op",
            "-labsl_leak_check",
            "-labsl_die_if_null",
            "-labsl_log_internal_conditions",
            "-labsl_log_internal_message",
            "-labsl_examine_stack",
            "-labsl_log_internal_format",
            "-labsl_log_internal_proto",
            "-labsl_log_internal_nullguard",
            "-labsl_log_internal_log_sink_set",
            "-labsl_log_sink",
            "-labsl_log_entry",
            "-labsl_flags_internal",
            "-labsl_flags_marshalling",
            "-labsl_flags_reflection",
            "-labsl_flags_private_handle_accessor",
            "-labsl_flags_commandlineflag",
            "-labsl_flags_commandlineflag_internal",
            "-labsl_flags_config",
            "-labsl_flags_program_name",
            "-labsl_log_initialize",
            "-labsl_log_internal_globals",
            "-labsl_log_globals",
            "-labsl_vlog_config_internal",
            "-labsl_log_internal_fnmatch",
            "-labsl_raw_hash_set",
            "-labsl_hash",
            "-labsl_city",
            "-labsl_low_level_hash",
            "-labsl_hashtablez_sampler",
            "-labsl_random_distributions",
            "-labsl_random_seed_sequences",
            "-labsl_random_internal_pool_urbg",
            "-labsl_random_internal_randen",
            "-labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes",
            "-labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes_impl",
            "-labsl_random_internal_randen_slow",
            "-labsl_random_internal_platform",
            "-labsl_random_internal_seed_material",
            "-labsl_random_seed_gen_exception",
            "-labsl_statusor",
            "-labsl_status",
            "-labsl_cord",
            "-labsl_cordz_info",
            "-labsl_cord_internal",
            "-labsl_cordz_functions",
            "-labsl_exponential_biased",
            "-labsl_cordz_handle",
            "-labsl_crc_cord_state",
            "-labsl_crc32c",
            "-labsl_crc_internal",
            "-labsl_crc_cpu_detect",
            "-labsl_bad_optional_access",
            "-labsl_strerror",
            "-labsl_str_format_internal",
            "-labsl_synchronization",
            "-labsl_graphcycles_internal",
            "-labsl_kernel_timeout_internal",
            "-labsl_stacktrace",
            "-labsl_symbolize",
            "-labsl_debugging_internal",
            "-labsl_demangle_internal",
            "-labsl_demangle_rust",
            "-labsl_decode_rust_punycode",
            "-labsl_utf8_for_code_point",
            "-labsl_malloc_internal",
            "-labsl_time",
            "-labsl_civil_time",
            "-labsl_time_zone",
            "-labsl_bad_variant_access",
            "-lutf8_validity",
            "-lutf8_range",
            "-labsl_strings",
            "-labsl_strings_internal",
            "-labsl_string_view",
            "-labsl_base",
            "-labsl_spinlock_wait",
            "-labsl_int128",
            "-labsl_throw_delegate",
            "-labsl_raw_logging_internal",
            "-labsl_log_severity",

            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "${fileDirname}/include/tiny_db.pb.cc",

            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"}

